# Change Typefaces at runtime for Textview

Tags: android, textview, android-fonts, android-typeface

I have a Custom `TextView` and i get all my Text from my Server, so i never know what style is coming. For Example this can include `bold`, `italic` and more `Textstyles`. But im not really sure how to handle that during runtime.

I created an `assets` Folder with all my Fonts i would like to use:

[image]

And in my CustomTextView i tried something like this:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

private static final String ANDROID_SCHEMA = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    applyCustomFont(context, null);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    applyCustomFont(context, attrs);
}

private void applyCustomFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    //Workaround for Preview Mode
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        int textStyle = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_SCHEMA, "textStyle", Typeface.NORMAL);

        Typeface customFont = selectTypeface(context, textStyle);
        setTypeface(customFont);

    } else {

        this.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
    }
}

private Typeface selectTypeface(Context context, int textStyle) {

    switch (textStyle) {
        case Typeface.BOLD: // bold
            return FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf", context);

        case Typeface.ITALIC: // italic
            return FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf", context);

        default:
            return FontCache.getTypeface("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", context);
    }
}

}
```

This is my FontCache Class:

```
public class FontCache {

//This caches the fonts while minimizing the number of accesses to the assets

private static final HashMap<String, Typeface> fontCache = new HashMap<>();

public static Typeface getTypeface(String fontname, Context context)
{
    Typeface typeface = fontCache.get(fontname);

    if (typeface == null)
    {
        try {
            typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontname);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

        fontCache.put(fontname, typeface);
    }

    return typeface;
}

 }
```

But thats not how it works, any Ideas how to accomplish this?
Thank you!

Comment: what is `FontCache`  ?

Comment: that looks fine. What's the issue ?

Comment: You should distinguish between typefaces and font styles. You can change the typeface via setTypeface but if you want to highlight only parts of your text that has to be done another way.

Comment: @Blackbelt FontCache is a technique used to prevent memory leaks on older android versions. Not needed if developing for 4.4.x+ versions.

Comment: @TorstenOjaperv I think you have a huge misunderstanding there. Accordingly to the code the OP posted, it is actually avoiding call `createFromAsset` multiple times.

Comment: @Blackbelt https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could override `setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style)`

```
@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
    Typeface customFont = selectTypeface(context, textStyle)
    super.setTypeface(customFont, style);
}
```

and from the outside you can call it like

```
 mTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```